# WPF Does not show data inside datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm following some example from and I cannot display data inside my datagrid. Worth to mention is that I'm getting data from db when looking inside debuger.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (session...)
        {
            using (transaction...)
            {
                var properties = new List<MyProperty>();
                // this variable is populated inside debugger
                properties = session.Query<MyProperty>().ToList();
                if (properties != null)
                {
                    MRDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                    MRDataGrid.Columns[1].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                    MRDataGrid.Columns[8].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" BorderBrush="Black"
        Background="AntiqueWhite" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="202" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,82,0,0" 
                  Name="MRDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="461" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Update

- I've changed to AutoGenerateColumns="True" in MainWindow.xaml
- Added MRDataGrid.ItemsSource = properties; in xaml.cs code
- What should I put inside ItemSource in MainWindow.xaml ?

Comment: You are not setting the ItemsSource

Comment: Umm ... try `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` ?

Comment: Where are you assigning the `DataContext` to the `MRDataGrid` sounds like a `Binding / Path` Issue you are having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting any context for `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` to work with.

Do something like `myDataGrid.DataContext=...` or bind the data context or change the `{Binding}` to point where you need it

Such as:

```
if (properties != null)
 {
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = properties;
    ...
```

Comment: I'm updated question, Not sure what to put inside ItemsSource= ?

Comment: @user1765862 try the edit, you can also try assigning properties to DataContext

Answer (score 0):

properties = session.Query().ToList();

MRDataGrid.ItemsSource = properties;

Answer (score 0):

Your datagrid doesn't have columns. You either need to declare them yourself or set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` You also need to assign the item source like Sten Petrov said